# Can we merge retina with retina-display

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, retag-request

The only time the word *retina* is of use on a site a bout technology is when talking about Retina displays. Since we aren't a Q&A site for Apple, I think it should the relevant tag should be called [retina-display](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/retina-display) since it could only be about the display.

Comment: Indeed, we aren't a biology site.

Comment: Maybe not "merge" but "rename"

Comment: so what is the non apple name for the high resolution displays coming out? shouldn't it be merged with that since "retina" is just a marketing term.

Comment: @Mateo doesn't that mean we should merge the term with whatever the general term for high-res displays are?

Comment: No because retina is specific for apple devices. True it should be a "cousin" of sort of a high resolution tag.

Comment: the problems when using a high resolution display are not specific to apple...

Comment: ...yet there is only 1 question with retina-display and none with retina

Answer (score 8, accepted):

And it's done. I renamed the [only question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231646/is-ubuntu-12-10-optimized-for-retina-displays) with [retina](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/retina) to [retina-display](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/retina-display).